# How to select columns from the dataframe based on variables from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to select only those columns from df2 which are equal to the variables of df1 in python pandas

df1

```
parameter (column name)

a
b
c
```

df2

```
w  x  a  c  z
3  1  5  6  1
5  67 4  3  56
8  12 6  1  23
```

my expected output is

```
a c
5 6
4 3
6 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) or [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for boolean mask:

```
df3 = df2[df.columns.intersection(df1['parameter'])]
```

Or:

```
df3 = df2.loc[:, df.columns.isin(df1['parameter'])]
```